# monaca で ui.sortable が動きません

Tags: monaca, angularjs

monaca + angularjsを使って、移動可能なタブをもったアプリを作成したいと思います。

monacaの最小限のテンプレートを使って、以下のページを参考に簡単なテストをしました。
http://qiita.com/nogson/items/1769ec56f3c652a74dc5

HTML

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ul ui-sortable ng-model="items">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

javascript

```
<script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.js"></script>
<script>
 angular.module('App', ['ui.sortable'])
   .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.items = ["いれかえたい", "とてもいれかえたい", "なんとかいれかえたい"];    
 }]);
</script>
```

monacaのプレビューでは、マウスで移動可能になるのですが、
実機デバッグをすると、スマホでは移動することができません。

特にエラーログは出ていません。

ui-sortableは、スマホでは（monacaでは？）使うことができないのでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己レスです。
スマホでは、「jQuery UI Touch Punch」を使うとできそうなことがわかりました。
http://ishi-14.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/05/04/172007

失礼しました。